# How to change the arrow head style in matplotlib annotate?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to change the head of an arrow in an annotation (`matplotlib`), but it doesn't work when used together with other properties, like `shrink`. It seems to change the type of object created, by looking at the parameters set.

---

**Example**

The following code shows two types of annotation arrows.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

xx = np.linspace(0,8)
yy = np.sin(xx)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(8,5))
ax.plot(xx,yy)
ax.set_ylim([-2,2])

ax.annotate( 'local\nmax', xy=(np.pi/2, 1), xytext=(1,1.5), ha='center', \
            arrowprops={'shrink':0.05})
ax.annotate( 'local\nmin', xy=(np.pi*3/2, -1), xytext=(5,0), ha='center', \
            arrowprops={'arrowstyle':'->'})
```

[image]

---

**Problem**

I tried to set the arrow type together with the other properties in the first annotation like this:

```
ax.annotate( 'other\nmax', xy=(np.pi*5/2, 1), xytext=(7,1.5), ha='center', \
            arrowprops={'arrowstyle':'->', 'shrink':0.05})
```

However, that line throws an error:

```
AttributeError: Unknown property shrink
```

---

**Why does it not work?**

**How do I change the arrow head style of an annotation?**

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36148773/how-to-change-the-head-size-of-the-double-head-annotate-in-matplotlib)

---

I am using:

python: 3.4.3 + numpy: 1.11.0 + matplotlib: 1.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Annotation), "if the dictionary has a key arrowstyle, a FancyArrowPatch instance is created with the given dictionary and is drawn. Otherwise, a YAArrow patch instance is created and drawn."

As you can see in the same link, `shrink` is a valid key for `YAArrow` but not for `FancyArrowPatch`.